# Publish/Subcribe Notification Service Over gRPC Using protobuf-net.grpc

Tags: c#, .net, publish-subscribe, protobuf-net, protobuf-net.grpc

I'm trying to write a notification system between a server and multiple clients using gRPC server streaming in protobuf-net.grpc (.NET Framework 4.8).

I based my service off of [this example](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/main/examples/wcf-port/SimpleStockTicker/src/TraderSys.SimpleStockTickerServer/Services/StockTickerService.cs). However, if I understand the example correctly, it is only able to handle a single subscriber (as `_subscriber` is a member variable of the `StockTickerService` class).

My test service looks like this:

```
private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;
private readonly Channel<Notification> _channel;

public ClientNotificationService(INotificationService notificationService)
{
    _notificationService = notificationService;
    _notificationService.OnNotification += OnNotification;
    _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Notification>();
}

private async void OnNotification(object sender, Notification notification)
{
    await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(notification);
}

public IAsyncEnumerable<Notification> SubscribeAsync(CallContext context = default)
{
    return _channel.AsAsyncEnumerable(context.CancellationToken);
}
```

`INotificationService` just has an event `OnNotification`, which is fired when calling its `Notify` method.

I then realized that System.Threading.Channels implements the Producer/Consumer pattern, but I need the Publisher/Subscriber pattern. When trying it out, indeed only one of the clients gets notified, instead of all of them.
It would also be nice if the server knew when a client disconnects, which seems impossible when returning `_channel.AsAsyncEnumerable`.

So how can I modify this in order to

- serve multiple clients, with all of them being notified when `OnNotification` is called
- and log when a client disconnects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, you'd need an implementation of a publisher/subscriber API; each call to `SubscribeAsync` will always represent a single conversation between gRPC endpoints, so you'll need your own mechanism for broadcasting that to multiple consumers. Maybe RX is worth investigating there

For 2, `context.CancellationToken` should be triggered by client-disconnect

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards RX. I rewrote my NotificationService to hold a Subject<Notification>, so now in ```SubscribeAsync``` I create a dedicated channel and pass ```n => channel.Writer.WriteAsync(n, context.CancellationToken)``` to my NotificationService as the OnNext action. Then the method returns ```channel.AsAsyncEnumerable(context.CancellationToken)``` (is it correct to use the same token?). I still don't know how to log when the token is cancelled, as with the return I lose control of it. And I'm unable to use the IDisposable used for unsubscribing from the NotificationService.

Comment: @user2727133 just don't "using" the register call; then it should get invoked even though you've exited that scope

Comment: I know, and that works, but then how do I unsubscribe?

Comment: @user2727133 pass the result of register to whatever needs to unsubscribe; or rewrite the thing that currently returns a sequence to *be* a sequence, and use "using"

Comment: Thanks for your help, I accepted this answer and added the solution to my question

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)

I rewrote the NotificationService like this, using System.Reactive.Subjects (shortened) - no need for an event, use an Action instead:

```
public class NotificationService<T>
{
    private readonly Subject<T> _stream = new Subject<T>();

    public void Publish(T notification)
    {
        _stream.OnNext(notification);
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(Action<T> onNext)
        return _stream.Subscribe(onNext);
    }
}
```

My updated ClientNotificationService, which is exposed as a code-first gRPC service:

```
public class ClientNotificationService : IClientNotificationService
{
    private readonly INotificationService<Notification> _notificationService;

    public ClientNotificationService(INotificationService<Notification> notificationService)
    {
        _notificationService = notificationService;
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<Notification> SubscribeAsync(CallContext context = default)
    {
        try
        {
            Channel<Notification> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Notification>(
                new UnboundedChannelOptions { SingleReader = true, SingleWriter = true });

            CancellationTokenSource cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(context.CancellationToken);

            using (_notificationService.Subscribe(n => channel.Writer.WriteAsync(n, cts.Token)))
            {
                await foreach (Notification notification in channel.AsAsyncEnumerable(cts.Token))
                {
                    yield return notification;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // canceled -> log, cleanup, whatever
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Note: Solution provided by OP on question section.</sub>